# Handling custom java exceptions with throwable cause in flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, exception

I am using a custom java exception to provide the flex client with more info than the exception itself. My exception extends Exception and it has a attribute with the needed info for the client.

Well, my problem is the following: when I build my exception if I invoke super() or super("message") the flex client can access all the info properly. But if I build the exception with a Throwable cause, super(cause), then the flex client can only access to stackTrace.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private String errorCode;

 public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

 public MyException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

By using MyException(String msg) the flex client can access to errorCode
By using MyException(Throwable cause) the flex client can´t access to errorCode

In the flex side the code is:

```
var faultEvent : FaultEvent = FaultEvent( event );
var errorMessage:ErrorMessage = faultEvent.message as ErrorMessage;
var codeError:String = errorMessage.rootCause.errorCode;
```

Do you know what is happening?

Comment: where is the code that throws `MyException`?

Comment: catch (final LDAPException e) {
                throw new MyException(e);
        }

Comment: __the flex client can´t access to errorCode__ - what do you mean?

Comment: The errorMessage.rootCause object does not contains that attribute. However if I don´t set a cause then the rootCause does contain the errorCode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `final`. 
Don't use the `final` keyword.

Comment: If I remove the final keyword the behavior is the same :(